# Running ffprobe on file lying in Azure Blob storage

Tags: java, azure, ffmpeg, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to get metadata of a file lying in Azure blob storage.

I am using ffprobe for this purpose. Though it works, since the ffprobe binary lies on my local system and file lies in Blob, the entire process is too slow

What would be the best way to do the above, getting meta data for a remote file?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways for your reference:

1.Use [blob.downloadAttributes()](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/v8.0.0/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlob.java#L1317),then use `blob.getMetadata()`

> This method populates the blob's system properties and user-defined
>   metadata. Before reading or modifying a blob's properties or metadata,
>   call this method or its overload to retrieve the latest values for the
>   blob's properties and metadata from the Microsoft Azure storage
>   service.

2.Use [get-metadata-activity in ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity).

Get a file's metadata:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for checking this, but The reason I am using ffprobe is because the files will be only media files. And ffprobe will be giving me meta data like the frame rate, video and audio codecs, bit rates etc. I dont think the blob meta data will be able to give me this information